# Will everyone be punished?

Tags: sin, punishment

Everyone has sinned and we sin all the time so will we be punished for these sins? Or will we enter heaven without a punishment if we repent out sins?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Allah say in Quran:

> On the Day We will say to Hell, "Have you been filled?" and it will
>   say, "Are there some more,"(**Surat Qāf,verse 30**)

And:

> ... "I will surely fill Hell with jinn and people all
>   together.'"(**Surat As-Sajdah,verse 13**)

This verses emphasize that the promise of Allah will happen, and Allah will fill Hell with jinn and people; and of course they will be punished there. This punishment is for jinns and people who err from the right way without repent out sins.

And what will happen for people who repent out sins? If it be a real repentance, with regret and leave the sin forever; then Allah is tawab and will forgive him/her; and He/she can go to heaven without punishment, as Quran say:

> And those who do not invoke with Allah another deity or kill the soul
>   which Allah has forbidden [to be killed], except by right, and do not
>   commit unlawful sexual intercourse. And whoever should do that will
>   meet a penalty.
>
> Multiplied for him is the punishment on the Day of Resurrection, and
>   he will abide therein humiliated -
>
> Except for those who repent, believe and do righteous work. For them
>   Allah will replace their evil deeds with good. And ever is Allah
>   Forgiving and Merciful.(**Surat Al-Furqān,verses 68,69,70**)

Imam [Ja'far al-Sadiq](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ja%27far_al-Sadiq) (a.s.) said:"some times some one does a sin and Allah will send him/her to heaven because of that sin."

Means that person will become fear about that sin and does real repentance which Allah will accept it and won't punish him/her.

But pay attention, It isn't for those who sin all of their life and want to repent out sins near their death.

> "But repentance is not [accepted] of those who [continue to] do evil
>   deeds up until, when death comes to one of them, he says, "Indeed, I
>   have repented now," or of those who die while they are disbelievers.
>   For them We have prepared a painful punishment."(**Surat An-Nisā',verse
>   18**)

Answer (score 6):

Bismillah.

Allah accepts repentance from any Muslim so long as his soul has not left his body. I.e, as long as he is still alive. That being said however, Allah will stop accepting repentance from any Muslim once the sun rises from the west and sets in the east. This is one of the major sins of al akhira (the day of judgement), in which every Muslim's book will be closed, and his dua'a will no longer be accepted by Allah.

However, only Allah can forgive anyone's sins, and only He knows whether your sins can be forgiven. There is not any sin that Allah cannot forgive except for shirk (associating anything with Him). Keep in mind that before ibless got kicked out heaven, he asked a favor from God. He asked Him to keep him alive until the day of judgement to guide the human race astray, and God accepted his favor. Therefore, God accepted the favor of the worst of Allah's creatures, and therefore can accept any dua'a or favors of any of his human creatures.

Just make sure that when you make repent or make a dua'a that you are sincere to Allah, and that you will try your hardest not to repeat the same sin again. Surely Allah knows best, and He loves to forgive your sins. Allah is the All Mighty and Kind.

Please inform me if I've made a mistake. Allah knows my intention and only He can forgive me for anything that I may be in fault.

Comment: Does it say in the Qur'an or is there a hadith stating sins will not be forgiven when the sun rises from the opposite direction. Also I know sins are forgiven however does that mean we will not be punished at all, well will enter jannah as long as we repent. I have heard that some people will go to Jahanum first to wash their sins then they will be let in Jannah if their sins are less.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure of hadith or ayat in the Qur'an (that is why I urge people to correct me if I'm wrong), but I believe that not one Muslim will enter Jannah if they have so much as a grain of salt of sin in their body. Although, as far as I know, Allah will either punish a Muslim in this world, in which they will be left with no punishment in the hereafter. Or, a Muslim will be punished in their grave, or in the day of judgement. But, of course, all sins my be forgiven by Allah at any time, including the day of judgement (I believe), in which no punishment will be undertaken.

Comment: Please inform me if I've made a mistake. Allah knows my intention and only He can forgive me for anything that I may be in fault.

Comment: I'm saying he might forgive us only after punishing us e.g. puting us in hell but not eternally, just to make up for our sins.

Comment: Well that's what I mentioned. If Allah were to punish someone, He might punish them in this world, in which they might be purified for the afterlife, and not be punished then. Others may have more sins, in which they will be punished in their grave, which will purify them before jannah, and thus not be punished in hellfire. Others however, will still have many sins on them after all these punishments, and will have to ensure further punishment in hellfire to be completely purified. So all in all, it depends on the accumulation of a muslim's sins that will determine his punishments